# Numpy doc star expression explanation

Tags: python, numpy, arguments, keyword-argument

'''numpy.sin(x, /, out=None, *, where=True, casting='same_kind', order='K', dtype=None, subok=True[, signature, extobj]) = <ufunc 'sin'>'''

This is an example of sin() function from np doc
Why is there an *arg after the out=None keyword argument? And why there are plenty more of args and kwargs in other docs too?

Answer (score 0):

https://peps.python.org/pep-0457/

The '/' and '*' delineate 3 types of parameters - positional and keyword:

```
def name(positional_only_parameters, /, positional_or_keyword_parameters,
     *, keyword_only_parameters):
```

So in

```
numpy.sin(x, /, out=None, *, where=True, casting='same_kind', order='K', dtype=None, subok=True[, signature, extobj])
```

`x` is always a positional

`out` may be positional (2nd) or keyword

`where` (and following) must be specified with keywords.